# how to parse json-in-json in php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have

```
{"foo":"bar","foo1":"bar1:\/bar2","foo3":bar3.bar3_decimal,"foo4":"{\"fooin\":\"fooinval\",\"fooin2\":\"fooinval2\"}"}
```

and another format generated by `php_json_encode(JSON.stringify(someJavascriptObjectAlreadyContainingJSON.stringifiedString))`

how can I parse it in php or using php+javascript(I can always write string to page, parse it if possible in javascript, send it back to server in simpler format). You can create first format by

```
json_encode(array('foo'=>'bar','bar2'=>JSON.stringify(some_javascript_obj))
```

Now I have written this data in a file. Now I want to decode it. How to do this, simple php json_decode() can't handle jsonstring in jsonstring.

I have some false json too, which I have no way but to parse manually. Thanks.

Comment: `json_decode($previouslyDecodedJson['foo4'])`. However, I don't get the point double serializing JSON

Comment: where will you get $previouslyDecodedJson['foo4']. All data is already written in plaintext(json-in-json) in file.

Comment: Pradeep because you didn't give us a variable name where the JSONString is held, @Cid made one up using a bit of descriptive logic

Comment: Its a single line of text after calling explode("\n",file_get_contents('foo_file'))

Comment: @Cid can you parse the first line of code in the above code?

Comment: You have to do it in 2 steps. 1. convert the outer json to a PHP data variable. Then convert the inner `'foo4'` JSONString to a PHP data variable. possibly followed by 3. put the 2 data items back togther

Comment: @RiggsFolly but how? I mean you are free to answer your own example parsed using your code.

Comment: Just checked:: You JSONString is not actually a valid JSON String

Comment: but this is a problem that is not unrealistic. It's probably common. calling `$line = json_encode(JSON.stringify(var foo={'foo':'bar','foo1':JSON.stringify({'foo2':'bar2'})});` I know we cannot write javascript in php but please do write php code in php and javascript code in javascript.

Comment: Again, what's the purpose of serializing twice?